# Catch the Process Timeout RuntimeException

Tags: symfony

In my project, I use the ProcessCompoment and I use a timeout of 120 seconds.

```
$process->setTimeout(120);
$process->run();

// executes after the command finishes
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    $job->setResult('error');
} else {
    $job->setResult($process->getOutput());
}
```

The problem is, when the timeout is reached Symfony return a `RuntimeException`, but I need to know when this command is aborted, to store an error in place of the result in my database.

Someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I just use a simple try-catch...

```
$process->setTimeout(120);
try {
    $process->run();
} catch (RuntimeException $exception) {
    $job->setResult('error');
}
```